# Create an AWS resource in 1000 AWS accounts using terraform provider meta-argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create an AWS resource in 1000 AWS accounts using terraform. I can use provider meta-argument however then I have to define the provider block 1000 times. This approach in not efficient and scalable. Is there a better way?

Comment: AWS Control Tower, AWS RAM, AWS Organizations.

Comment: I don't think it vise to try to do this with one tf file. You will have one state file for 1000 accounts you should aim to have it account specific. You should use an orchestral deployment tool instead.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately terraform currently does not allow to create providers in child modules with for_each or count.